# Visual Studio Community: how to view data or run SQL in the "SQL Server Object Explorer"

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

You can "explore" the schema etc. using the SQL Server Object Explorer in VS.

However, I can't find a way to view the data in a given table (at least the first page), or to run some arbitrary SQL.

Is this possible?

I also have the full blown Microsoft SQL Server Manager installed, but this can't "see" the databases created by Visual Studio in its built-in SQL Server Express instance. It can only connect to its own full blown SQL Server databases.

I have looked for a tool to view data in SQL Server Express, but have not found anything yet. There does not seem to be a version of Microsoft SQL Server Manager for SQL Server Express unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do a "New Query" on any database node to run a query window:

[image]

And then you can do a "View Data" on any table, in SQL Server Object Explorer:

[image]

But you should also be able to load any "LocalDB" instance and view it from the full-fledged SQL Server Management Studio (at least since SSMS v17, where it's a separate, free download)....